# What determines the sign of m % n for integers?

Tags: python, modulo, integer-division

The modulo in Python is confusing.

In Python, `%` operator is calculating the remainder:

```
>>> 9 % 5
4
```

However:

```
>>> -9 % 5
1
```

Why is the result `1`? and not `-4`?

Comment: This wikipedia article on [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation) should clear it up

Answer (score 14):

Because in python, the sign matches the denominator.

```
>>> 9 % -5
-1
>>> -9 % 5
1
```

For an explanation of why it was implemented this way, read the [blog post by Guido](http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html).

Comment: ooops sry i meant why is the answer 1 and not -4?

Comment: `-4+5 = 1`, match the sign

Answer (score 5):

-10 % 5 is 0, ie, -10 is evenly divided by 5.

You ask why -9 % 5 is not -4, and the answer is that both 1 and -4 can be correct answers, it depends on what -9 divided by 5 is. Of course -9 divided by 5 is 1.8, but this is integer division, in Python 3 represented by //, so I'll use // here to be clear that it's integer division we are talking about.

I'll explain this by not using negative numbers, it's easier.

9 // 5 is 1. Ie, you can subtract 5 from 9 only 1 time, and the rest is 4. But if you subtract 5 from 9 one more time, well, then the rest becomes -1!

**So -1 is a correct answer to 9 % 5, if 9 // 5 is 2.**

In Python 9 // 5 is 1, because the Python integer division is a floor division, ie it always rounds *down*. If it has rounded *up* 9 // 5 would be two, and 9 % 5 would have been -1.

Now lets look at the case when we use negative numbers: -9 divided by 5 is now -2. **Because it is floor division, it always rounds down.** That means that the rest is 1. So -9 % 5 is 1, not -4.

Answer (score 3):

This really has to do with how python rounds integer division.

Mathematically, the following has to be true always for any int x and y

```
x == (x // y) * y + x % y
```

So from this, we can say

x % y == x - (x // y) * y

Now recall that python rounds integer divison toward negative infinity, not toward zero.
For example -9 // 5 gives -2, not -1. With this logic, you obtain -9 % 5 = 1

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like this:

0 % 5 is 0

1 % 5 is 1

So... what if you go backwards?

-1 % 5 must be 4

-2 % 5 must be 3

and so on.

You'll see that following this -9 % 5 is 1

NOTE: Depending on the programming language and the implementation of %, you might get different results since programmers disagree on how to handle negative numbers in %

Comment: maybe i have this understanding of % all wrong. if x%y, doesnt that represent the remainder after x has been divided into y?

Comment: It represents something slightly different, but incredibly useful. Basically, it allows you to mod numbers and consider them to be in ranges of 0 to n-1 even when they go negative. The link wim posted gives an example of why you might want this: http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: could you explain why 3%7 is 3. i mean by my logic up there, 3 is the remainder after 3 has been divided into 7?? im confused :(

Comment: Yes, 3%7 is 3. And 0%7 is 0, and -1%7 is 6 - because 6%7 is also 6, and (m+a*n)%n always equals m%n for any positive or negative integer a. (e.g. you can subtract or add 7 and still get the same remainder)

Answer (score 0):

In integers, you can't always pick such a quotient that `quotient * divisor == dividend`. If the `product` does not equal the `dividend`, one always has to make a choice, whether to make it slightly less than the `dividend`, or slightly greater than the `dividend`. The sum of the `product` with the `remainder` makes the `dividend`, that's what the `remainder` is. In any case, the dividends and products have to be close, meaning the absolute value of the remainder has to be less than that of the divisor.

When the `divisor` is positive, the `products` increase as the `quotients` increase; when the `divisor` is negative, the `products` decrease as the `quotients` increase. In the first case, the products go from the below, in the second case, the products go from the above. In Python, in both cases the next `quotient` is only taken when the `dividend` reaches the next possible `product`, going the same way the products go. Before that, only the `remainder` changes to accommodate for the next `dividend`, again always going in the same direction as the dividends change, without a break at zero. This rule is universal in Python, it holds always.

That is not the reason why this choice had been made, but that gives the idea what happens (i. e. why the results are what they are, and which results to expect).